# Block sealing failed err="unauthorized signer"

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, windows

i am trying to run geth environment on windows after i have successfully set it up on linux. When trying to deploy contract on geth like i did in linux it produces following error.

```
 loadScript('contract.js')
INFO [03-12|11:41:37.126] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash=ae591c…7d2135 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0       fees=0            elapsed=0s
INFO [03-12|11:41:37.126] Submitted contract creation              fullhash=0xbaf4bbcf3794d28b561c437cf2cc9bab1f4dab3824a039f44810bc7d8cf566fc contract=0x513b725b5d9369690800a10803e52daCC4BFDb1e
INFO null [objec[0t3 -O1b2j|e1c1t:]4
1:37.126] Sealing pausedt,r uweaiti
ng > for transactions
WARN [03-12|11:41:37.153] Block sealing failed                     err="unauthorized signer"
INFO [03-12|11:41:37.153] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash=eb4c1f…eb0b05 uncles=0 txs=1 gas=1387245 fees=1.387245e-12 elapsed=27.021ms
```

Every step is as it was in case of linux.

Following is genesis.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 786,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "constantinopleBlock": 5,
    "clique": {
      "period": 0,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5c820746",
  "extraData": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001bf178cacf17f566b1223e3e45dbddb0c20e7030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "5313f537528ef5348676b0e42b6a87792005bf5e": {
      "balance": "1000000000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

And this is the command i used for running geth.

```
geth --datadir data --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8501  --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,ne
t,web3,txpool,miner' --ws --wsport 8502 -wsapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --wsorigins="*" --networkid 786 --gasprice '1' -unlock '0x5313f537528ef
5348676b0e42b6a87792005bf5e' --password data/password.txt --mine console
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I created new account but forgot to add it in "extra data". Now it works.

Comment: For those wondering, the "extra data" stuff is the property of the genesis file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using another `etherbase` address (that was default).

From `geth --help`:

```
  --miner.etherbase value             Public address for block mining rewards (default = first account)
```

Check it in your logs (`Etherbase automatically configured  address=0x...`) and make sure it's right. If not, correct it using the above flag.

---

Or maybe *it's NOT unlocked*. Then you need to unlock it:

```
  --unlock value                      Comma separated list of accounts to unlock
```