# Could someone help me understand how this problem was solved?

Tags: signature, geth-debugging

[Block sealing failed err="unauthorized signer"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68249/block-sealing-failed-err-unauthorized-signer/107407?noredirect=1#comment131107_107407)

The answers that are given still have me confused and I don't know how to interpret what's being said. Tried to search up some of the terms used by both the account that answered their own question as well as the other account that tried to simplify the first answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing to obtain such error message? What type is the blockchain? PoA, PoW, .. Do you run geth? if that is true what is the geth command line? From the error message it looks like the node you are using has been configured to sign blocks but it isn't a validator so any block created by it is ignored.

Comment: @Ismael This error was generated when I try to unlock my node within Git Bash. The consensus engine is PoA with the command being ,"./geth --datadir node1 --unlock "SEALER_ONE_ADDRESS_HERE" --mine --rpc --allow-insecure-unlock". It worked with my MetaMask wallet on a PoW attempt but has this issue as I try PoA. I am running geth. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `--mine` parameter forces geth to create a block but from the error message the address isn't a validator (block sealer) and it failes. So either remove `--mine` parameter so it doesn't trie to mine, or add that address to the sealer list.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification